# Pade approximation for a function of 2 matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, pade-approximation

Is there any successful examples of using Pade approximation to calculate a function of 2 matrices, such as computing $C(A, B)$ such that $e^C = e^A e^B$? I know that Pade approximation has been applied to compute a function of 1 matrix, such as matrix logarithm, but I have never seen any successful application of Pade approximation to a function of 2 matrices.